# What is the formula for average daily trading volume calculated by Google Finance formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, google-finance

Average daily trading volume is obtained by this formula `GOOGLEFINANCE("Symbol", "volumeavg")` on Google Spreadsheet. How is the average volume calculated? Based on how many days of moving average?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the internal operationss of a vendor-supplied service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juan F Miguez has [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-finance/-D8q7j5hI98) "30 days" and a spot test has indicated it is around that period.

> Average volume used in finance market is 50 days.
>   Presently google finance makes the average for 30 days.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do the following:

- get the last x many days' volume for a ticker (I used 80 to be safe since there are weekends, and holidays for when the market is closed)
- query the 50 records descending by date, (for a 50 day moving average use 50, for other averages use your own limit)
- get just the prices
- average

  ```
  =average(index(query(googlefinance("AAPL","volume",today()-80,today()), "select * order by Col1 desc limit 50"),0,2))
  ```